# USB WiFi card is not recognized as network interface

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface

I have Lemaker Guitar board with Debian 8 based OS on it. The board has two network interfaces - ethernet and on-board WiFi chip. I need to use third interface - USB WiFi card. `lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The first line is my USB WiFi card so drivers are properly installed because system recognizes it right? But I don't see it in `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:4e:fd:3a:bf:62
          inet addr:10.42.0.223  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f64e:fdff:fe3a:bf62/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6032008 (5.7 MiB)  TX bytes:6236134 (5.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:32

ip6tnl0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          NOARP  MTU:1452  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1216 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1216 (1.1 KiB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:c7:09:36:d0:9a
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

`eth0` and `wlan0` are the two interfaces built in the Lemaker Guitar board. Not really sure what are `ip6tn10` and `sit0` interfaces, but since they have no HW address I assume they are not my USB WiFi card (plus they remain there when I unplug it). So I guess my question is, how do I make it work? How to tell my system that `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.` is a network interface?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got it working. Copy paste from Lemaker forum:

```
copy the provided .ko file to /lib/modules/3.4.xxx/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
then run "sudo depmod -a" from a terminal
then run "sudo modprobe -f mt7601Usta"
```

and I downloaded the .ko file http://mirror.lemaker.org/MT7601.tgz

Comment: And the way to debug it is to look into `dmesg`. There you would have seen that even though `lsusb` "recognizes it" (i.e. the USB device gets enumerated), it doesn't load a driver for it. Also, you shouldn't need `modprobe` the next time once you've run `depmod`, the kernel module should load automatically (if it's correctly written).